# How to translate erlang error messages into user friendly text in elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir

I recently got the following error when I was trying to read a file in elixir.

```
iex()> File.read("no_existant_file.csv")
{:error, :enoent}
```

Luckily I knew what "enoent" meant and quickly realised that this was because I had a typo in the file name. Once I fixed this everything worked as expected.

However, this made me wonder if there was a way to change this error message into a more "human friendly" message that could potentially be displayed to an end user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function I was after in this question is the erlang function `:file.format_error`.

Using the example above

```
iex()> {:error, error_msg} = File.read("no_existant_file.csv")
{:error, :enoent}

iex()> error_msg
:enoent

iex()> :file.format_error(error_msg)
'no such file or directory'
```

Using `:file.format_error/1` we can see that the error is now a lot more user friendly